# Was it inappropriate in 19th century Canada to wear flowers in a hat to church?

Tags: 19th-century, canada, church

(Not sure if this should be on the Literature SE)

From the novel *[Anne of Green Gables](https://gutenberg.org/files/64365/64365-h/64365-h.htm)*, Anne wears a hat with flowers in it to church, and is criticized by her neighbour and adoptive parents for it:

> It was not until the next Friday that Marilla heard the story of the flower-wreathed hat. She came home from Mrs. Lynde’s and called Anne to account.
>
> “Anne, Mrs. Rachel says you went to church last Sunday with your hat rigged out ridiculous with roses and buttercups. What on earth put you up to such a caper? A pretty-looking object you must have been!”
>
> “Oh, I know pink and yellow aren’t becoming to me,” began Anne.
>
> “Becoming fiddlesticks! It was putting flowers on your hat at all, no matter what colour they were, that was ridiculous. You are the most aggravating child!”

This is weird to me, since I can easily imagine someone doing this in the modern world without getting much comment, in fact there are vendors selling exactly [these kind of hats](https://www.etsy.com/market/floral_church_hats).

Was it inappropriate to wear flowers in a hat to church in 19th century Canada? I tried Googling for it but can't tell what the appropriate search terms are (they're clearly not "flowers church hats" which led to the vendor's link above).

Comment: I looked it up, and the most likely denomination for a PEI resident would probably have been Presbyterian. Do the books make this clear?

Comment: @T.E.D. I ctrl+F'ed the book for "Presbyterian" and didn't see anything. Does it matter?

Comment: The context was being in a church, and there's a legit relationship between denominations and culture. Calvinists and Quakers in particular traditionally have frowned on bright colors and ostentatious dress.

Comment: @T.E.D. hmm maybe this should be in the Christianity SE then.

Comment: Interesting question.  As @T.E.D. said, the [author's denomination was Presbyterian](http://www.gov.pe.ca/hpo/index.php3?number=1022313).  If you decide to bring this question to Christianity.SE, one way to frame it to make it acceptable is to ask from the point of view of 19th century Canadian Presbyterian teaching, since it has to be connected with a theology or a church practice question.

Comment: @Anonymous - I don't know that **this** question would be on topic there, but the question of what denomination that church in the book belongs to might fly there. Possibly Literature too, but I'd check on that before posting.

Comment: When I read this book, my impression was that it wasn't just "wearing flowers" but going way overboard and wearing heaps and heaps of flowers in a way that clearly demonstrated a lack of perspective. Anne frequently engages in obsessive and extreme behavior that goes right along with this. My father's family is from a similar cultural background as the author (rural Scottish Presbyterian, but not from PEI specifically), and I can confirm that there are no specific sartorial prescriptions, but there is a general rule against showoffishness and obsessive and extreme displays of vanity.

Comment: Anne refers to being struck by the words of the nineteenth paraphrase: "Quick as the slaughtered squadrons fell
In Midian’s evil day". These words do occur in Paraphrase 19 of the Church of Scotland, which is Presbyterian. This seems to confirm tht Anne was attending a Presbyterian church, modelled on the C of S.. https://www.bible.com/bible/3051/ISA.9.MP1781

Comment: Neither the minister nor the Sunday School teacher expressed any concern, and nobody sems to have complained that Anne's hat was immoral. It was just mentioned in passing the following Friday to Marilla. There is no suggestion by anybody in the book that it was morally or religiously inappropriate. It is simply that she looked ridiculous, since different from other girls

Comment: @T.E.D. There is a reference in the book to paraphrase 19, which is Presbyterian.